# Tf has two or more unconnected trees. Error

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I create the node that gives me the distance between the center of my robot which is my base link and some fixed point in the map. It was running and getting the correct distance but after a while (after playing differnt bag files) i start getting strange disttances I got this error at the begiing of calculation

Could not find a connection between '/base_link' and '/door2' because they are not part of the same tree.Tf has two or more unconnected trees.

This is my node

```
    #include <ros/ros.h>
#include <tf/transform_listener.h>


int main(int argc, char** argv){
  ros::init(argc, argv, "my_tf_listener");

  ros::NodeHandle node;
  tf::TransformListener listener;

  ros::Rate rate(10.0);

  while (node.ok())

    {
    tf::StampedTransform transform;
    try{
      listener.lookupTransform("/base_link", "/door1",  
                               ros::Time(0), transform);
    }
    catch (tf::TransformException ex){
      ROS_ERROR("%s",ex.what());
    }


    double x = transform.getOrigin().x();
        double y = transform.getOrigin().y();
    double dist1 = sqrt(x*x + y*y);
    ROS_INFO("%f", dist1);

    rate.sleep();


  }
  return 0;
};
```

And this the label in the launch file

Any help???

This my frames.pdf[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41980/tf-has-two-or-more-unconnected-trees.-error/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2012-08-21

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-08-22**:
I add the pdf. frame. Any help?

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-08-22**:
You are now having a different problem that has nothing to do with the original question. Please open a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can view the connection between the frames by executing "rosrun tf view_frames". It helps getting an overview of tf.

---

Originally posted by [Aslund](https://answers.ros.org/users/163/aslund/) with karma: 289 on 2012-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-08-22**:
i have a strange pdf saying no tf data recieved, When should I execute the g "rosrun tf view_frames"??

**Comment by [Aslund](https://answers.ros.org/users/163/aslund/) on 2012-08-22**:
You should run it while you program is running. It will read all frames in the system and generate a pdf showing the connection between the frames

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-08-22**:
Ok. Still no data recieved. Whats the problem?

**Comment by [Aslund](https://answers.ros.org/users/163/aslund/) on 2012-08-22**:
Apparently your system is not publishing any tf. Seems very strange, I wonder if you are executing it properly. Have you just jumped into programming with ROS or have you spend time with reading the tutorials?  Have you tried to execute your node after the static_transform_publisher?

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-08-22**:
I got it. I got the pdf now. Any help now?

**Comment by [Aslund](https://answers.ros.org/users/163/aslund/) on 2012-08-22**:
Try changing your transform to:

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-08-22**:
Sorry, Dont understand. What to change???

**Comment by [Aslund](https://answers.ros.org/users/163/aslund/) on 2012-08-22**:
Your static_transform_publisher to the one I showed you. Instead of door2 having world as parent then will door2 be the parent. It avoid having two threes. Had a smilar problem and this fixed it. You can see it here: http://answers.ros.org/question/41000/problems-with-tf-using-the-navigation-stack/

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-08-22**:
ok. Will try. thanks

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-08-22**:
I changed and is not ok. It gives me the wrong distance

**Comment by [Aslund](https://answers.ros.org/users/163/aslund/) on 2012-08-22**:
What is the distance and what should it be? Just telling it is wrong is neither helpful for me or you. I noticed I accidently wrote door2 in my code instead of door1, did you fix that mistake?

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-08-22**:
Well the distance is changing during the time. should be in the range of 0 to some like 10 meters. But I got totaly uncenece datas.. like start from 5 and than go till 15 . So no cence results

**Comment by [Aslund](https://answers.ros.org/users/163/aslund/) on 2012-08-22**:
Atleast your problems with the tf tree is solved. I am a bit unsure whether the values are correct from static_transform_publisher, but if the position of the door is wrong according to the world frame (you can use RViz) you must change them accordingly

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-08-22**:
How do I know if my  position of the door is wrong? Why that changes? The door is fixed in the map frame. I do not understand that

**Comment by [Aslund](https://answers.ros.org/users/163/aslund/) on 2012-08-22**:
As I wrote, use RViz: http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz/UserGuide. You can see how the frames moves over time. You claim your results are uncertain but to me it just looks like you are dealing with an offset. Either wrong position of the door or something else

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to use [listener.waitForTransform](http://ros.org/doc/fuerte/api/tf/html/c++/classtf_1_1Transformer.html#a72dc26fe7bfcb9585123309e092e5c83) before you call `lookupTransform`. Have a look at [this tutorial](http://ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials/tf%20and%20Time%20%28C%2B%2B%29).

It takes a while until the listener object received the complete tree. Until then you might have disconnected trees.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-08-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-08-22**:
Yes , but even after that is gives me not the correct distance. The distances just increased all the time. And before that was given the correct one

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-08-22**:
Please fix the code above. Seems like there went something wrong with copy-pasting it. Also, get rid of the includes of btQuaternion.h, btScalar.h. You should never use hard-coded include paths and you should not include anything from bullet when using tf anymore.

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-08-22**:
Sorry dont understand what you mean not include anything from bullet when using tf anymore. My problem is that once tf is running ok but next time with the same or other bag file ist totaly noncence. I dont get that